# Page Layout of Songs Package problems

Tags: page-breaking, margins, paper-size, songs

I'm creating a Songbook from the [`songs` package](http://songs.sourceforge.net/).

Currently I am having an issue with the format of the page. If the song is too long it doesn't break on the page end and goes to the second column.

Here is an example of what's happening:

[image]

I'm trying to debug this but I can't find out where is the error.

Here is the code of my `.tex` file:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,onecolumn]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[chorded]{songs}
\usepackage{a4wide}
\usepackage{pslatex}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{ebgaramond}

\ifchorded
  \newcommand{\stopchords}{\chordsoff}
  \newcommand{\resumechords}{\chordson}
\else
  \newcommand{\stopchords}{}
  \newcommand{\resumechords}{}
\fi

\renewcommand\printchord[1]{\sffamily\slshape\small#1}
\noversenumbers

\begin{document}
\songsection{Andrés Calamaro}
\begin{songs}{}
\beginsong{Flaca}[by={Andrés Calamaro}]
\beginverse
\[G]Flaca, no me cl\[B7]aves
tus puñ\[Em]ales, por la esp\[C]alda
tan prof\[G]undo, no me du\[D]elen
no me hacen m\[G]al.    \[D7]
\endverse
\beginverse \stopchords
Lejos, en el centro
de la tierra, las raíces
del amor, donde estaban
quedarán. 
\endverse
\beginverse \stopchords
Entre no me olvides me dejé nuestros abriles
olvidados, en el fondo del placard
en el cuarto de invitados, eran tiempos dorados
un pasado mejor. 
\endverse
\beginverse  \stopchords
Aunque casi me equivoco y te digo poco a poco
no me mientas, no me digas la verdad
no te quedes callada, no levantes la voz
ni me pidas perdón. 
\endverse
\beginverse \stopchords
Aunque casi te confieso yo también he sido un
perro compañero, un perro ideal
que aprendió a ladrar y a volver al hogar
para poder comer.
\endverse \resumechords
\endsong
\nextcol
\beginsong{Cuando te conocí}[by={Andrés Calamaro}]
\beginverse
\[C]Cuando te conocí ya no \[E7]salías 
con el \[Am]primero que te había \[Em]abandonado 
no \[F]vale la pena \[C]hablar 
de aquellos \[F]años pasados \[Dm] \[G] 
\endverse
\beginverse  \stopchords
Cuando te conocí ya no salías 
con aquel chico casado 
que te prometía que la dejaría 
y todavía no se había divorciado 
\endverse
\beginverse  \stopchords
Cuando te conocí, salías 
con un amigo de los pocos que tenías 
eras lo mejor de su vida 
pero fuiste lo mejor de la mía 
\endverse
\beginverse  \stopchords
Cuando te conocí miré por un agujero 
en tus pantalones 
y dos años después 
ya tomabas todas las decisiones 
\endverse
\beginverse  \stopchords
Cuando te conocí 
te reconocí por tus botas 
y mientras tomabas tequila 
dejamos atrás dos almas rotas 
\endverse
\beginverse  \stopchords
Cuando te conocí me dijiste 
que por mí no ibas a cambiar 
ibas a seguir siendo igual, 
ibas a seguir siendo igual 
\endverse
\beginverse  \stopchords
Y en el fondo es tan hondo mi dolor 
porque me voy, y no se puede cambiar 
de corazón como de sombrero 
sin haber sufrido primero
\endverse
\beginverse \stopchords
Y en el fondo es tan hondo mi dolor 
porque me voy, y no se puede cambiar 
de corazón como de camisa  
\resumechords \[F] sin \[G]perder la \[C]sonrisa.
\endverse 
\endsong
\scleardpage
\beginsong{Paloma}[by={Andrés Calamaro}]
\beginverse \resumechords
\[C]Mi vida fuimos \[G]a volar 
\[Am]con un solo \[Em]paracaídas 
\[F]uno sólo va a \[C]quedar 
\[F]volando a la \[G]deriva 
\endverse
\beginverse \stopchords
Vivir así no es vivír 
esperando y esperando 
porque vivir es jugar 
y yo quiero seguir jugando 
\endverse
\beginverse \stopchords
Le dije a mi corazón 
sin gloria pero sin pena 
no cometas el crimen, varón 
si no vas a cumplir la condena 
\endverse
\beginverse \stopchords
Quiero vivir dos veces 
para poder olvidarte 
quiero llevarte conmigo 
y no voy a ninguna parte 
\endverse
\beginverse \stopchords
No te preocupes, Paloma 
hoy no estoy adentro mío 
tu amor es mi enfermedad 
soy un envase vacío 
\endverse
\beginverse \stopchords
No te preocupes Paloma 
no hay pájaros en el nido 
dos ilusiones se irán a volar 
pero otras dos han venido 
\endverse
\beginverse \stopchords
Si me olvido de vivir 
colgado de sentimiento 
voy a vivir para repetir otra vez 
este momento 
\endverse
\beginverse \stopchords
Te bajaría del cielo, mujer 
la luna hasta tu cama 
porque es muy poco de amor 
sólo una vez por semana
\endverse
\beginverse \stopchords
Puse precio a mi libertad 
y nadie quiso pagarlo 
te cambio tu corazón por el mio 
para mirarlo y mirarlo 
\endverse
\beginverse \stopchords
Ampas de gloria, mujer 
quiero un pedazo de cielo 
para invitarte a dormir 
en la cama o en el suelo 
\endverse
\beginverse \stopchords
Un sacrificio ritual bien o mal 
yo quiero hacerle a mi estrella 
sin principio ni final 
no puedo vivir sin ella.
\endverse 
\endsong
\beginsong{Estadio Azteca}[by={Andrés Calamaro}]
\beginverse  \resumechords
\[Em]Prendido, a tu botella \[C]vacía
esa que antes\[G], \[B7]siempre tuvo gusto a nada
\[Em]apretando los dedos, \[C]agarrandome
dándole mi vida\[G],\[B7] a ese paraa\[Em]valanchas.
 \[G] \[Em] \[C] \[G] \[B7] \[Em]
\endverse
\beginverse \stopchords
Cuando era niño, y conocí el Estadio Azteca
me quedé duro, me aplastó ver al gigante
de grande me volvió a pasar lo mismo
pero ya estaba duro mucho antes.
\endverse
\beginverse \resumechords
Dicen que \[C]hay, dicen que \[G]hay
un mu\[B7]ndo de tenta\[Em]ciones
tambi\[C]én hay cara\[G]melos
con for\[B7]ma de cora\[Em]zones.
dicen que \[C]hay bueno ma\[G]lo,
\[B7]dicen que hay más o \[Em]menos
dicen que \[C]hay algo que te\[G]ner
\[B7]y no muchos te\[Em]nemos,  \[G] \[Em] \[C] \[G]
\[B7]y no muchos te\[Em]nemos. \[G] \[Em] \[C] \[G] \[B7] \[Em]
\endverse
\beginverse
Prendido a tu botella vací\[C]a
esa que an\[G]tes siempre tuvo gusto a nada.
\endverse
\endsong
\end{songs}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX!. Read [this](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) to familiarize further with our format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don’t know why exactly, but the reason for your problems is `a4wide.sty`. You should try to recreate what it does with the `geometry` package. The documentation suggests that this should do, but the double zero margins are definitely wrong:

```
\usepackage[textwidth=6.375in, left=0in, right=0in, marginparwidth=0.75in]{geometry}
```

Comment: Thanks. I used 0.75in for left and right magins and it's ok now...